# Alterar window.location.href não redireciona para a nova página

Tags: javascript

O if está a funcionar mas o `window.location` não vai para o google é somente um exemplo mas penso que explique o erro.

```
function eliminaParagem (){
    var confirma =confirm("Tem a certeza que quer eliminar a paragem");
    if (confirma==true){
        window.location.href="wwww.google.pt";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Queres que vá para uma página interna ou externa?

Comment: Queres que vá para uma págna externa ou interna?

Comment: Experimente usar apenas `window.location`, com o `http` (se for página externa).

Comment: Esse tipo de comportamento é peculiar quando, por exemplo, o botão que aciona a rotina de redirecionamento está dentro de um <form> com submit, ou mesmo nas linhas abaixo do </form>. Uma solução, é colocar o botão (ou link) acima da tag <form>

Answer (score 5):

Quando se trata de links externos tens de por `http://` antes do endereço.

```js
function eliminaParagem (){
    var confirma =confirm("Tem a certeza que quer eliminar a paragem");
    if (confirma==true){
        window.location.href="http://www.google.pt";
    } 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="eliminaParagem();">Google</button>
```

Comment: O teu código não funciona pelo menos no chrome e no mozila não envia para o google.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo do que você gostaria, só redirecionar sem que a pessoa nem veja o conteúdo da página, é melhor usar `window.location.replace('//sitegenerico.com')` porque nesses casos o navegador nem salva o site que pediu o redirecionamento no histórico da pessoa. Se quiser mudar de página como se clica em um link é melhor usar o `window.location.href = '//sitegenerico.com'`.

Quando mudando a página pra um site externo é aconselhado usar um link protocol-less (sem o `http:` ou `https:`), apenas as duas barras `//`. Exemplo do google: `//google.com`

Answer (score 0):

O `window.location.href` propriedade retorna a URL da página atual, por exemplo, se eu abrir colocar no console o comando abaixo na página dessa pergunta, teremos o retorno da URL dessa pagina:

**Script:**

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

**Retorno:**
    `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129417/windows-location-n%c3%a3o-funciona`

Repare que o retorno teve com `http://` dessa forma para atribuir um novo valor para o `window.location.href`, também devemos colocar o protocolo `http`, pois assim referencia uma nova URL, caso não coloque ele entenderá que é uma página interna do seu site.

Conforme seu código, sem o `http` na frente iria retornar algo assim:

```
https://www.seusite.com/www.google.pt
```

Fazendo a alteração o seu script fica assim:

```
function eliminaParagem (){
    var confirma =confirm("Tem a certeza que quer eliminar a paragem");
    if (confirma==true){
        window.location.href="http://www.google.pt";
    } 
}
```

Dessa forma redirecionando para outro site.

Comment: Não funciona o seu código no chrome ou no mozila nao funciona em ambos

Comment: Pode [edit] sua pergunta e colocar como está chamando essa função, pois fiz alguns testes aqui e funcionou, o exemplo da resposta do @Pedro, funciona aqui também, contextualize melhor seu problema, assim conseguiremos resolver da melhor maneira possível :)

Comment: Eu usei o código do Pedro através do "Executar trecho de código" e nada aconteceu para alem disso testei no meu próprio código e nada aconteceu mais uma vez.

Pode ser algum problema dos navegadores que estou a usar? mozilla e chrome

Comment: testa o comando via console do navegador, no caso sem a função somente  o principal, `window.location.href="http://www.google.pt";` e veja se retorna algum erro

Comment: Comentar na consola funciona

Comment: apresenta algum erro ?

Comment: Não não dá nenhum erro