# Redirecionamento em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Porque ele não redireciona para a página digitada em URL?

```js
function irPara(url){
    url = document.irParaURL.URL.value;
    return location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<form name="irParaURL">
    <label>Dígite um site:</label>
    <input type="text" name="URL" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Ir" onclick="irPara()">
</form>
```

Comment: editei a resposta e melhorei o script para não dar erros com espaços e com `https` também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque na função uma condicional, para verificar se `http://` ou `https://` foi digitado, se não foi concatena na url

```
function irPara(url){
    url = document.irParaURL.URL.value;
    url = url.trim(); //Remove espaços em branco no inicio e fim
    var httpString = "http://";
    var httpsString = "https://";
    if (url.substr(0, httpString.length).toLowerCase() !== httpString && url.substr(0, httpsString.length).toLowerCase() !== httpsString)
    {
        url = httpString + url;
    }

    return location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: funcionou !! valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Na linha na qual você colocou

```
     return location.href = url;
```

Você deve colocar, caro queira substituir a página atual pela url digitada pelo usuário

```
    window.open(url, _self);
```

Comment: com a função window.open(url) ele abre outra janela e não redireciona para a url.. não resolveu...

Comment: Editei a resposta para melhor visualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Retire o return.
Se for link externo, vc precisa adicionar o http:// ou https://

[Alterar window.location.href não redireciona para a nova página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129417/alterar-window-location-href-n%C3%A3o-redireciona-para-a-nova-p%C3%A1gina)