# Como redirecionar para uma action no asp.net mvc, utilizando jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Como redirecionar para uma action no ASP.Net MVC, utilizando JQuery?

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
 $("#Filtro").change(function () {
     @Url.Action("Answer");
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Existem alguns exemplos aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129417/alterar-window-location-href-n%C3%A3o-redireciona-para-a-nova-p%C3%A1gina), e o comando é [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/location) passando o valor do endereço, ***exemplo***:

```
$("#Filtro").change(function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Answer")';
});
```

para que seja redirecionado para a página desejada.

***Referencias***

- [JQuery: window location href](https://www.linhadecomando.com/jquery/jquery-window-location-href)
- [Alterar window.location.href não redireciona para a nova página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129417/alterar-window-location-href-n%C3%A3o-redireciona-para-a-nova-p%C3%A1gina)
- [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/location)